# The controller for URI "/agregarPedido/1" is not callable

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony and wanted to ask for a help, I 'm from Argentina and so forgive me for my poor English. este es mi routing.yml:

```
Agregar_pedido:
    pattern: /agregarPedido/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AtajoBundle:Tablas:agregarPedido }
```

And here is my TablasController.php:

```
public function agregarPedido($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $usuario = $em->getRepository('AtajoBundle:User')->find($id);
        $pedido = new Pedido();
        $pedido->setProducto('Yeso');
        $pedido->setCantidad('200');
        $pedido->setValor('50');
        $pedido->setUnidad('kg');
        $pedido->setFecha(new \Datetime());

        $pedido->setUser($usuario);

        //$em->persist("$usuario");
        $em->persist("$pedido");
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('El nuevo pedido agregado es el ' . $pedido->getId() . ' al cliente '. $id . '');
    }
```

the error that arises is the following:

The controller for URI "/agregarPedido/1" is not callable.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the correct parameter name is `path`, not `pattern`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should append the word Action to your method to make it a valid action:

```
public function agregarPedidoAction($id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I had not noticed it . you saved me

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help you :)